# Call to a member function bind_Param() in get method

Tags: php, mysqli

I wonder whats the problem in my code? I tried all the sources I can search but it still gives me the same error which is still "Call to a member function bind_Param() on a non-object".here's my code.,hope someone can help me, thanks

```
$app->get('/students/:student_id',function () use($app){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id =:student_id";
    try {
        $db = connect_db();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bind_Param("student_id", $student_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $students = $stmt->fetchObject();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($students); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
});
```

Comment: `the same error.` What error?

Comment: Call to a member function bind_Param() on a non-object

Comment: What is the content of your `connect_db()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works:

```
$app->get('/students/:student_id', function ($student_id) use($app){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = ?";
    try {
        $db = connect_db();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bind_Param("i", $student_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $students = $result->fetch_object();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($students); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
});
```

I assume that you're using this definition of the `connect_db` function:

```
function connect_db() {
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="user";
    $dbpass="pass";
    $dbname="stackoverflow-33750846";
    return new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);;
}
```

Perhaps there is a bit of confusion using the database connection and read data from it, so I add some points:

- Be sure to pass `$student_id` as a parameter to the callable function;
- [`$stmt->bind_Param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) accepts a string that represents the type of the parameters and all the binding parameters;
- [`fetchObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) is a function of the [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class.

Comment: Hi @DianaraBathan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.